# How to give parameters to hashmap getMethod

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
public static Map< String, Method > supplierFunctionMap = new HashMap< String, Method >();
    static
    {
        try {

            supplierFunctionMap.put( "11111-200", SupplierConfiguration.class.getMethod("supplier_X"));
            supplierFunctionMap.put( "11111-210", SupplierConfiguration.class.getMethod("supplier_X"));

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void supplierHasConfig(String supplierNumber) throws IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException
    {        

        supplierFunctionMap.get(supplierNumber).invoke(null);  
    }

    public static void supplier_X() throws NotesException{
```

Now what I want to do is the following. I want to add an extra parameter to supplier_X. So for example supplier_X(int supplierNumber).

Now in the code above I call the method via a HashMap. How do I add these parameters into the hashmap?

Comment: Am I correct saying that you want to know how to pass parameters into `public static void supplier_X()` stored in your map?

Comment: Correct. supplier_X this one I want to give a parameter so I also need to invoke it into the mapping somehow

Comment: which parameters do you want to add? You can simply provide arguments, what's the issue?

Comment: updated my answer. I can put arguments into the method, no problem. But as you can see in the code I try to call the method via a HashMap, how to put parameter values there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change signature of method to declare desired arguments

   ```
   public static void supplier_X(Object arg1, Object arg2) throws NotesException {
   ```
2. Invoke your `Method` passing desired values

   ```
   ...
   supplierFunctionMap.get(supplierNumber).invoke(null, new Object(), new Object());
   ...
   ```

   replace `new Object()` with actual type and values you want to pass.

[`Method.invoke()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-) takes an object on which you want to execute the method as first parameter (in your case you are passing a `null` since method is `static`) and list of arguments to pass in method.

Hope it helps!

Edit: if you want to tied up parameters create wrapper class to store parameters and `Method` together

```
class MethodWithParameters {
    private Method method;
    private final List<Object> parameters = new ArrayList<>();

    // get, set
}
```

And use such class as a value of your `Map`

```
Map<String, MethodWithParameters> supplierFunctionMap = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: (in your case you are passing a null since method is static) and list of arguments to pass in method) Can you please explain this one.

Comment: @YdB, `static` methods belong to the class, so you can call them without the need to create class instance. To invoke such methods with Reflection API you can pass `null` as a first parameter to `Method.invoke()`.

Comment: I now have: public static void supplier_X(String supplierNumber) throws NotesException{ 
and 
supplierFunctionMap.get(supplierNumber).invoke(null, supplierNumber); 
And the hashmap is:
 supplierFunctionMap.put( "1111-200", SupplierConfiguration.class.getMethod("supplier_X"));

But I get a noSuchMethodException

Comment: @YdB, you want to pass `supplierNumber` "1111-200" in your method?

Comment: I want to pass 1111 as value to my method

Comment: Oh, that's because you've incorrectly get method reference while populating map. Try this `SupplierConfiguration.class.getDeclaredMethod("supplier_X", String.class)`

Answer (score 0):

This will helps you:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        supplierHasConfig("11111-210");
    }

    public static Map<String, Method> supplierFunctionMap = new HashMap<String, Method>();

    static {
        try {

            supplierFunctionMap.put("11111-200", Test.class.getMethod("supplier_X", String.class));
            supplierFunctionMap.put("11111-210", Test.class.getMethod("supplier_X", String.class));

        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void supplierHasConfig(String supplierNumber) {
        Object[] obj = {"Hi"};
        try {
         supplierFunctionMap.get(supplierNumber).invoke(Test.class.newInstance(), obj);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException |InstantiationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

    public static void supplier_X(String param) {
        System.out.println(param);
    }
}
```